# make seaborn heatmap bigger

Tags: visualization, pandas, plotting

I create a `corr()` df out of an original df. The `corr()` df came out 70 X 70 and it is impossible to visualize the heatmap... `sns.heatmap(df)`. If I try to display the `corr = df.corr()`, the table doesn't fit the screen and I can see all the correlations. Is it a way to either print the entire `df` regardless of its size or to control the size of the heatmap?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you want to print `df.corr()` or change the size of the heatmap?

Comment: @Gilbert You can do masking of the heatmap such that either the upper half or the lower half are only displayed

Comment: Ideally, I want to increase the heatmap size.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found out how to increase the size of my plot with the following code...

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
sns.heatmap(corr)
```

[image]

Comment: Check the answer yourself please :-)

Answer (score 4):

This would also work.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax=subplot(111)
sns.heatmap(corr,ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
```

`plt` is not always defined, I can use seaborn without `plt`.

To use the above line you need to also import plt like:

```
from matplotlib import plt
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to increase the default figure size in your plotting tool. You need to import matplotlib and set either default figure size or just the current figure size to a bigger one. Also, seaborn is built on top of matplotlib. You need to install and import matplitlib to make the best use of seaborn library.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work and allows for scale to be parameterized. Figure size can even be adjusted after plotting.

```py
fig = plt.gcf()  # or by other means, like plt.subplots
figsize = fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_size_inches(figsize * 1.5)  # scale current size by 1.5
```

[`fig.set_size_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches)

[`fig.get_size_inches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.get_size_inches)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sn.heatmap(cm,annot=True)
```

> You can increase Heatmap size by using `plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))`